# Working with daylight saving time with the DateTime class

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, dst

I'm in the process of porting a C++ program to C#. The program needs to be able to read a file's "modified" timestamp and store it in a `List`. This is what I have so far:

C# code:

```
ret = new List<Byte>(); //list to store the timestamp

var file = new FileInfo(filename);

//Get revision date/time
DateTime revTime_lastWriteTime_LT = file.LastWriteTime;

//Copy date/time into the List (binary buffer)
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Month));
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Day));
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Year % 100)); // 2-digit year
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Hour));
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Minute));
ret.Add(Convert.ToByte(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Second));
```

The problem occurs when I read in the `Hours` value. If the file was modified during daylight savings time (like a summer month), the hour value in the C++ program gets subtracted by one. I can't seem to replicate this in my program. In the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) for `DateTime` it says under "DateTime values": "local time is optionally affected by daylight saving time, which adds or subtracts an hour from the length of a day". In my C# code I made sure to change my `DateTime` object to local time using, `ToLocalTime()`, but apparently I haven't instituted the option that the article is talking about. **How do I make sure that my DateTime object in local time subtracts a value when reading in a file that was modified during daylight savings time?**

C++ code just in case:

```
static WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA get_file_data(const std::string & filename)
{
  WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ret;
  if (!GetFileAttributesEx(filename.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &ret))
    RaiseLastWin32Error();
  return ret;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
static SYSTEMTIME get_file_time(const std::string & filename)
{
  const WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA data(get_file_data(filename));
  FILETIME local;
  if (!FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&data.ftLastWriteTime, &local))
    RaiseLastWin32Error();
  SYSTEMTIME ret;
  if (!FileTimeToSystemTime(&local, &ret))
    RaiseLastWin32Error();
  return ret;
}

void parse_asm()
{
    // Get revision date/time and size
    const SYSTEMTIME rev = get_file_time(filename);
    // Copy date/time into the binary buffer
    ret.push_back(rev.wMonth);
    ret.push_back(rev.wDay);
    ret.push_back(rev.wYear % 100); // 2-digit year
    ret.push_back(rev.wHour);
    ret.push_back(rev.wMinute);
    ret.push_back(rev.wSecond);
}
```

**Update for clarity:**

In Windows time settings I am in (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada). The file was last modified on Tues Sept 03, 2013 at 12:13:52 PM. The C++ app shows the hour value as 11 and the C# app shows the hour value as 12 using the code above. I need the C# app to show the same hour value as the C++ app.

Comment: Ignore the binary buffer bit - what happens if you just print out `revTime_lastWriteTime_LT`? How does that compare with what's displayed in the file system? Note that on my box, `LastWriteTime` already returns a `DateTime` with a kind of `Local`, so calling `ToLocalTime` shouldn't make any difference. Is it possible that the problem is actually with the C++ code (which you haven't shown)?

Comment: `DateTime` has `IsDaylightSavingTime()` method

Comment: Converting historical timestamps to local time is fraught with trouble, you need a reliable database that knows when DST was in effect in previous years.  You can typically count on .NET getting that right,.  C++, no, not very likely.  If you can't change it to use UTC instead, like it should, then keeping that C++ code happy is your cross to bear, use TimeZoneInfo.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't think that calling `ToLocalTime` made a difference, but I was just trying it after reading the MSDN article. I am sure that the problem isn't with the C++ code. I'm basically in a situation where the C++ file is always right, haha. I tried to print out `revTime_lastWriteTime_LT.Hour.ToString()` and it didn't subtract an hour.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Isn't that just a boolean property?

Comment: @Ericafterdark yes, you may check it and subtract an hour if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. `LastWriteTime` is already local time, why do you need to subtract anything? There is also `LastAccessTimeUtc`, this won't be affected by daylight saving time.

Comment: You still haven't said how the file system displays the result. It would be helpful if you'd give a concrete example - again, how you're storing the date is irrelevant here.

Comment: You should also have a look at `LastWriteTimeUtc` - what value does that have? And what time zone are you in?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm in EST. The file system stores a list of bytes and then outputs them as a binary file. I am viewing the files in hex, sorry for not specifying sooner.

Comment: Well stop doing that, to start with - just use `Console.WriteLine(revTime_lastWriteTime_LT)`, as it'll be much simpler. Now, as I've asked before, please give an example with what the operating system shows in the file system, and what the .NET app shows, and what the C++ app shows. Also, please tell us the *exact* time zone as displaying in the Windows time settings. There are multiple time zones which are broadly referred to as "Eastern Time".

Comment: In Windows time settings I am in (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada). The file was last modified on Tues Sept 03, 2013 at 12:13:52 PM. The C++ app shows the hour value as 11 and the C# app shows the hour value as 12 using the code in my question.

Comment: So C++ shows the time as it is in winter. You may use `LastWriteTimeUtc` with `AddHours(TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset)`.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but `AddHours()` takes a double and won't take `TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is actually not with .NET, but with your C++ code.   You're using `FileTimeToLocalFileTime`, which has a well known bug, as described in [KB932955](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932955):

> **Note** The `FileTimeToLocalFileTime()` function and the
>   `LocalFileTimeToFileTime()` function perform the conversion between UTC
>   time and local time by using only the current time zone information
>   and the DST information. This conversion occurs regardless of the
>   timestamp that is being converted.

So in the example you gave, Sept 03, 2013 at 12:13:52 PM in the US Eastern Time zone should indeed be in daylight saving time.  But because it is *right now* (February 2015) not daylight saving time, you currently get 11 for the hour in your C++ program.  If you run the exact same C++ code after next month's transition (March 8th 2015), you will then get 12 for the hour.

The fix for the C++ code is described in the remarks section of the [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724277.aspx) for the `FileTimeToLocalFileTime` function:

> To account for daylight saving time when converting a file time to a local time, use the following sequence of functions in place of using `FileTimeToLocalFileTime`:
>
> 1. `FileTimeToSystemTime`
> 2. `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`
> 3. `SystemTimeToFileTime`

Now that you understand the bug - if you actually wanted to keep that behavior in C# (which I do *not* recommend), then you would do the following:

```csharp
TimeSpan currentOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
DateTime revTime_LastWriteTime_Lt = file.LastWriteTimeUtc.Add(currentOffset);
```

The better thing to do would just to leave your current code as is (using `file.LastWriteTime`), and call the bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks for all the information @MattJohnson! If I get the approval to fix the bug I'll definitely use your answer. However, if I need to keep the bug, what's different from your answer and @NadiaChibrikova's? It seems like they accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Nadia's answer will *always* ignore DST.  My answer (at the end) will match the behavior of the C++ bug - which is to use DST if it is *currently* in effect, regardless of the timestamp.  Again - I recommend you simply leave the C# code as you originally showed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you need to use `Add` not `AddHours`, `Add` accepts `TimeSpan`. So you're looking for:

```
 file.LastWriteTimeUtc.Add(TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset);
```

Comment: Thank a lot @NadiaChibrikova. Do you know why this produces the same result as the C++ code? It seems like this is an extra step that the C++ code doesn't ever deal with.

Comment: Internal representation of time is ticks (100 ns). How it then converted to days and hours depends on the language. .Net Framework has a better support for DST and I wouldn't call it a disadvantage. I can't think of many cases where you need to ignore DST.

Comment: I'm not sure that you would actually want to do this.  This would effectively ignore daylight saving time, even if it was applicable in the local time zone.